# Cannot Chroot into a directory but can cd into it

Tags: ssh, sftp, vsftpd

When connecting to an SFTP server i have no problems Chrooting into the /home directory and accessing the directory i want (FileFolder). But when i attempt to configure it so it Chroots straight in to the directory it rejects the connection.

When i change the following line `ChrootDirectory /home` to `ChrootDirectory /home/FileFolder` my connection is rejected when connecting as a guest user. Permissions for the guest user are `rx` since i want the user to only be able to download files.

I did try adding logging to my config to maybe have a grasp on what is happening:

```
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
```

But the file `/var/log/auth.log` does not exist (I might be mistaken and it logs to a different file).
I also tried using `journalctl _COMM=sshd` but it does not give me detailed information, only users that are connecting and their IPs.

My sshd_config:

```
Port 22

PubkeyAuthentication yes

AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM yes

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

Match Address 192.168.8.*
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match User guest
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /home
```

I have tried the solution [from here](https://serverfault.com/questions/709013/sftp-server-chroot-initial-directory) but it does not work.

P.S. I am connecting from 192.168.8.* IP address so it is not pubkey authentication error.

Solution: I had to change the owner of FileFolder to root. Initially it was just a user with root privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect permissions issue.
Why chroot to /home is working is that it's owned by **root**.
Chroot to **/home/FileFolder** is not working because it's not owned by root and should be writable only by root.
All the elements in the **chroot** path should have the same privilege.
Check  "/var/log/secure" for log info.
It will list the reason chroot is failing.

Comment: The owner of this folder was indeed not root. I changed the owner to root and it worked perfectly. Thank you.